# JetBrains GoLand, disable highlighting test files

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

How do I turn off the highlighting of text files in the GoLand IDE from JetBrains? With such a traffic light, it is difficult to perceive the file structure. I would like to turn it off once and for all. I didn't find how to do it in the settings.

[image]

chat gpt, goolge, crying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings — Appearance & Behavior — File Colors — Test files. There is an option to remove file type association from this list.

[image: Settings screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Another pointless IDE feature switched off (code folding being another)